# Кого называли "варягами"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, история

Раз уж тут стали популярны разговоры о призвании на Русь варягов, то задам такой вопрос: А кого вообще называли "варягами"? Кто это такие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну в первом значении варяги = норман(н)ы.  Причем норманы - скандинавские, не те, что осели во французской Нормандии, хотя исторически это родственные племена.
"Из варяг в греки" = со Скандинавии в Малую Азию.
Потом уже развилось варяг - гость, пришелец. Но такое значение в историеских хрониках невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Ср.-лат. varangus - "телохранитель, воин из наемной стражи визант. императоров".
Заимств. из др.-сканд. *váringr, væringr, от vár "верность, порука, обет", т. е. "союзники, члены корпорации".
http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-1648.htm

Смысл в том, что варягов нанимали для выполнения военных задач. Наемники, потому этимология наиболее логична, на мой взгляд.

Немного не в тему о происхождении этимологии Синеуса и Трувора:
"Синеус" -- sine bus -- "свой род".
"Трувор" -- thru waring -- "верная дружина". 
http://lib.ru/HISTORY/RYBAKOW_B_A/russ.txt_with-big-pictures.html

Т.е. варяги пришли на наши территории либо как наемники, либо как союзники. Что одно другому не мешает. Рюрик пришел с армией и семьей... Наличие призыва по Нестору "властвовать нами" говорит о том, что власть и так по сути была в виде того же вече. К тому же какой дурак призовет властвовать инородцев с другой культурой, другим языком и т.п.? В вече сидели не дураки же..."

Из Форума об этимологии слова "варяг"

http://forum.istorichka.ru/perma/2010/07/16/russian/1279260888

Comment: <<"Синеус" -- sine bus -- "свой род".
"Трувор" -- thru waring -- "верная дружина".>> -  за уши притянуто, (как, впрочем и почти все у Рыбакова (если этот тот Рыбаков). Даже если оставить за скобками весьма условную схожесть фонетике, откуда такие имена могли появиться у реальный людей?! То, что имтория с "призванием на княжение" - древний фейк, раскрущенный Карамзиным, не оспаривается.